# Run command line shp2pgsql in C# function?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, c#

I'm developing an application web with ASP.NET/C# and I would in a button importing the shapefiles into PostGIS, and I'm trying with this code, this code I'm using it in cmd.exe in Windows it imported but in the application no but it can't import the shapefiles and it can't send me what'is the error, can you have idea?

```
if (strFileType == ".shp")
    {
    txtFilePath.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedShap/" + strFileName + strFileType));
    string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploadedshap/" + strFileName + strFileType);

    // Connection String to shapefiles
    string[] strCmdText = {"cd ..","cd ..","cd program files","cd postgresql","cd 9.4","cd bin","shp2pgsql -s 3857 '"+ strNewPath+ "' public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d is -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami"};
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",String.Join(" ",strCmdText));
    }
```

Comment: You could try a pipe (https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) in the string for strCmdText to capture the output text.. The hard part of shell execute is that you can't see what happens in the window as it flashes up and is gone too quickly; other methods don't even show the window. To set the system environment variables as alexGis states use SetEnvironmentVariable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx (this has often worked for me)

Comment: can you rectifay in the code i don't understand you

Comment: "shp2pgsql -s 3857 '"+ strNewPath+ "' public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami > C:\\DEBUG.TXT" will (probably) capture the output of the operation to file c:\Debug.txt so you can see any error messages with notepad. Often, as I have said, I need to set environment variables for the process when using GDAL/OGR; the environment variables for the cmd process should be the same as the program that spawned it, try alexGis answer also.

Comment: can you explain me, i'm using this but it can't do it "string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = @"shp2pgsql -s 3857 '"+ strNewPath+ "' public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami > C:\\DEBUG.TXT";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\CMD.exe", strCmdText);
"

Comment: What error message (if any) are you getting? Is the command being run but no output? What happens when you start a command window (windows + r, then type cmd) and paste that text into it with the value for strNewPath filled in. Does strNewPath contain spaces? Is c:\debug.txt being created, if so what's in that file? Can you try to run the command like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results ?

Comment: i'm trying this solution but it can't, my problem is how i can learn this command in the c# code because it can't read it  "string strCmdText; strCmdText = @" 3857 "+ strNewPath +" 'public.COMGEO -s shp2pgsql | psql -h localhost i2s -d -u postgres -p 5432 -w alami> C: \\ debug.txt "; System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (@" C: \ Program Files \ PostgreSQL \ 9.4 \ bin \ CMD. exe ", strCmdText);"

Comment: but why? The first place to look is non-escaped strings but you seem to have that well in hand, the other is spaces in the path, which need an extra level of quoting in the command. Try the Process method I gave a link for instead of instantiating like you are without control and step-debug to see where it's going wrong. Another method is to write to a batch file your command and then execute the batch file, that way you can check the *exact* command that is to be executed should it fail and if needed set some environments first.

Comment: yes i'm trying by this but it can't can you send me your example code to try with it pleassssssssssssse

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your operating system PATH variable to include the directory "c:\programs\postgresql\9.4\bin"

There should be no need to tell your OS where the command "shp2pgsql" lives inside your code, the PATH variable should do that. Navigating to the variable from some previous unknown directory makes for very fragile code.

Comment: or I have to add that path

Comment: i'm trying by this but it can't resolve the problem  string[] strCmdText = {"shp2pgsql -s 3857 '"+ strNewPath+ "' public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami"};
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\CMD.exe",String.Join(" ",strCmdText));

Comment: #alexGIS it can't compiled can you help me

Comment: You don't need the path to CMD.exe, your OS already knows that. You need specify the path to shp2pgsql.

Comment: #alexGIS but how i can do it can you help me please i(m doing this command (string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = @"shp2pgsql -s 3857 c:\comgeo.shp public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\CMD.exe", strCmdText);)

Comment: it is like this that it can't do it !!

Comment: #alexGIS i'm trying by this but it can do it "         string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\shp2pgsql -s 3857 c:\comgeo.shp public.COMGEO | psql -h localhost -d i2s -U postgres -p 5432 -w alami";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);"